# Angularjs : escape double quotes in ng-click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, double-quotes, quote

i have this function to escape quotes

```
$scope.escapeQuotes= function(str) {
return str 
        .replace(/('|\")/g, "\\$1")
        .replace(/("|\")/g, "\\$1")
}
```

in the HTML : i have

```
<button ng-click=getValue($escapeQuotes(the"question")) >the "question " </button>
```

it works for single quotes, but not for double quotes, how can I edit function for passing the value with double quotes

Comment: you can't, you have to escape them directly in the HTML. The escape only makes sense before the DOM parsing.

Comment: `.replace(/(['"])/g, "\\$1")` would be fine.

Comment: @AvinashRaj why your regex would work better than OP ?

Comment: no need for pipe character since we are doing single char orring.